# Will the following function achieve my goal of ignoring stale responses?

Tags: javascript

I have a search function that is debounced. It is called each time a `keyup` event is fired on a text area.

The idea that results are fetched as the user types in the text area.

```
{
  search: _.debounce(search, 200),
}
```

But, there is no guarantee AFAICT that the search calls to the backend will return in the order they were sent (network latency, server vagaries), meaning that the results could (although unlikely) correspond to an earlier search term.

So I want to cancel (or at least ignore the response to) any in-flight requests when a search is performed.

**I have two questions:**

- Is this a real problem that needs solving? (I have not seen it solved before), and
- Will the following code help me achieve this?

```js
function ignoreStale(fn) {
    var latest = 0;
    return function() {
        var id = ++latest; // increments latest too
        return fn.apply(this, arguments)
          .then(function(result) {
              if (id !== latest) {
                  throw new Error('Stale callback.');
              }
              return result;
          });
    }
}

var callCount = 0;

var o = {
    foo: ignoreStale(foo),
};

function foo(val) {
    callCount--;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, val), (5000 + callCount*200));
    });
}

function go (val) { 
  o.foo(val).then(doSomething).catch(error);
}

go('1'); // returns third
go('12'); // returns second
go('123'); // returns first

function error(err) {
    document.write(err, '<br/>');
}

function doSomething(val) {
    document.write('Doing something:', val, '<br/>');
}
```

Presumably cancellable promises would help, but I am using vanilla JS.

Comment: Instead of calling it each time a key-up events, can't you add a timer in that event, so it needs to pass 1 second at least from last key pressed by user, to send the search request?

Comment: That is the purpose of the debounce

Comment: There is an `abort` method for XHR https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is. Are you just looking for the term, or do want a solution (i.e. code)?

Comment: My question has evolved now that I have written a solution. I'll re-word the question.